# Office 365 API - Create meeting rooms

Tags: office365, exchange-server, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm doing an integration of my platform with the Office 365 Calendar through the Microsoft Graph API.

I plan to import and create new meeting rooms, but I've checked documentation that all of the rooms in this API are in beta and only allow the user to list the rooms.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create new rooms through the API?

I have read [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findrooms) and have not found this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to create Room resources through Microsoft Graph API. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this as a suggestion.

Currently you can only create Room and Equipment Resources via the [Office 365 Admin Portal](https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/ResourceMailbox) or the [Exchange Admin Center](https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/?rfr=Admin_o365&exsvurl=1&mkt=en-US&Realm=officedev.ninja&RpsCsrfState=b993598e-e7bf-a52a-0668-5e172aa0fde5&wa=wsignin1.0).